# Custom links in facebook share post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there still a way to add custom links to links footer in facebook share post (e.g. next to "Like - Comment - Share" below the text of text of the post itself)? Some "link" parameter or something, maybe? Or is it deprecated now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current API, I don't see any way to add additional links to a feed posting other than in the content of the message or as the primary link of a feed link share.